# "Uninstalling Package Failed" error persists in Production Org

Tags: managed-package, deployment, error-messages

Problem in uninstalling package from production Org.

Error Code : Error Number: 1418461257-25979 (2077356007)

Solved all Dependency Errors while uninstalling package that were received .But still it shows "Uninstalling Failed" in Status bar , have received emails with above Error code.

Comment: Best bet is to raise an actual support case with Salesforce.

Comment: How did you find the error code?  I have the same issue but am not getting an error anywhere?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get more information on the error is to raise a case with SalesForce and quote the error number:

> Error Code : Error Number: 1418461257-25979 (2077356007)

Comment: Interesting point about this type of errors, is the bit in brackets is a stack trace hash, meaning that if you get a few of them you can at least tell if it is the same internal issue. The first number is a a kind of log timestamp from what i gather.

Answer (score 1):

Errors of this nature mean than an unhandled exception occurred in the underlying application server that powers Salesforce.  There's no pattern to this and nothing really that you can do with the information aside from raise a case with Salesforce and wait for them to fix it.

I have been able to gain access to application server log snippets through some of my Salesforce connections when I have hit managed package problems (installing rather than uninstalling), but it was no help to be honest, as I had no idea of how the code had been written.  The only thing I could tell was that it was something to do with a workflow component, but I had loads of those and very little capability to change them due to the managed nature of the package.

I have asked developer support in the past if there is anything that I can do to try to workaround these errors or get more information and the answer has always been no - something went wrong at a low level and needed a code fix to resolve.

Comment: I've had simalar conversations and experiences with them, talking with them lately they do recognise this is not ideal and are committed to putting more effort into surfacing the Metadata errors in the uninstall failure emails. Time will tell of course...

Answer (score 1):

One of possible reasons for uninstall failed when you assign permission set from a managed package as member of the Community. Then an uninstall will fail.

Additional error might be sent to email including:

```
could not be removed during uninstall.
null: You can't delete this permission set because it is used in an experience.
```

If you receive uninstall errors, try to check your email for any clues.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it was just a managed package permission set was included in a subscriber org permission set group